# GET Twitter user & token URLs

Tags: objective-c, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0

On his blog post about [LROAuth2Client - OAuth2 for iPhone and iPad applications](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/oauth2-for-iphone-and-ipad-applications.html), Luke Redpath states:

> If possible, you should try and obtain the end-user and token URIs at runtime rather than hardcoding them into your application. This can be typically done by making an unauthorised request to a secure URI and obtaining them from the WWW-Authenticate header in the returned 401 response.

Please provide example code of how this is done in order to implement [Sign in with Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter) on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

According to [@alancfrancis](http://twitter.com/#!/alancfrancis) on Twitter, ["You just hard code them."](http://twitter.com/#!/alancfrancis/status/77767977696641024)

I think these are the correct URLs:

```
#define kTwitterTokenURL @"http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
#define kTwitterUserURL  @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not currently support Oauth 2. You will have to use [OAuth 1.0a](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth). The WWW-Authenticate header returned from Twitter [does not contain](https://apigee.com/console/apigee-console-snapshots-1306904400000_67860d52-946f-49d6-b4a1-1dc3d0985e88/rendersnapshotview) the token URIs so you will have to hardcode them in your application.